# Can an interactive report display the original column name in Apex?

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex, interactive

Is it possible for an interactive report to show the original column's name instead of "Beautifying" it? Example: column name is `data_id` but it is displayed `Data Id` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, nothing prevents you to type any **heading** you find appropriate. `data_id` included.

---

If you wanted Apex to use exact column names by default, I'm not aware of such an option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah I'm looking for an automated solution within Apex (or just finding out if it's actually possible).